# Using if and else statements error

Tags: php, url, get

I have created two links where I would like the page contents to change. The problem is the URL changes but not the page content.

```html
<h3>Filter Results</h3>
<p><a href="index.php?filter='Action'>Action</a></p>
<p><a href="index.php?filter='Comedy'">Comedy</a></p>
```

```php
if (isset($_GET['filter']) == 'Action') {
    echo 'Action';  
}
else if (isset($_GET['filter']) =='Comedy') {    
    echo 'Comedy';
}
```

It always outputs the first link information "Action".

Answer (score 7):

Your links are faulty:

```
<p><a href="index.php?filter=Action">Action</a></p>
<p><a href="index.php?filter=Comedy">Comedy</a></p>
<!--                         ^    ^ No single quotes (' ') -->
```

**[Yogesh Suthar pointed it out first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17877676/871050)**

Also, **[`isset()`](http://php.net/isset)** will return a boolean (`true` or `false`; based on whether or not the variable **is set**). You're comparing a boolean to a string, *[a string will always be converted into `TRUE`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)* (unless the string is "false" or similar), so basically, if the variable is set, the first condition will always match.

You want

```
if (isset($_GET["filter"]) && $_GET["filter"] === "Action")
```

Note the use of `===`, this will make sure that the variable is exactly what you think it is, and not some sort of other type variable.

### Few more points <sub>(Shamelessly <s>stolen</s> taken from other answers)</sub>

- If there are multiple possible filters, check for the variable existance once, and use a `switch/case` block to determine which of them it is:

  ```
  if(isset($_GET['filter'])) {
      switch($_GET['filter']) {
          case 'Action':
              echo 'Action';
              break;
          case 'Comedy':
              echo 'Comedy';
              break;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Yeah posting this in the chatroom.. oh well that's clever anyway :)

Comment: @Herbert: Seeing as my answer is (now was) the top voted answer, I wanted to include all the goodness from the other answers, so that OP doesn't need to read it in fragments.

Comment: Yeah, I was j/k. I wish more people would do that and tidy up the place a bit. :)

Comment: There is a typo in your HTML. You are missing a double quote in the first line after `Action`

Comment: @byf-ferdy: You're right. Next time, feel free to suggest an edit and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 5):

The function [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) will only check if the variable is existing! It will not return its value! Try this instead:

```html
<h3>Filter Results</h3>
<p><a href="index.php?filter=Action">Action</a></p>
<p><a href="index.php?filter=Comedy">Comedy</a></p>
```

```php
if(isset($_GET['filter']) && $_GET['filter'] == 'Action'){
    echo 'Action';  
}

else if(isset($_GET['filter']) && $_GET['filter'] == 'Comedy') {
    echo 'Comedy';
}
```

Also, using switch might make things easier in the future:

```html
<h3>Filter Results</h3>
<p><a href="index.php?filter=Action">Action</a></p>
<p><a href="index.php?filter=Comedy">Comedy</a></p>
```

```php
if(isset($_GET['filter'])) {
    switch($_GET['filter']) {
        case 'Action':
            echo 'Action';
            break;
        case 'Comedy':
            echo 'Comedy';
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Lars Ebert the Url changes but nothing is outputted to the page as aspected

Comment: @SamuelHughesMensah I changed the link-urls, there were some errors. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17877676/2580794

Comment: @LarsEbert. The code is 100% working. Thanks. I failed to copy it well. Sorry bro

Comment: @SamuelHughesMensah Then go ahead and mark one of the answers as a solution!

Answer (score 3):

As @MadaraUchiha said about `isset` and,

```
if(isset($_GET['filter']) == 'Action')
```

should be

```
if(isset($_GET['filter']) && $_GET['filter'] == 'Action')
```

Also

```
<a href="index.php?filter='Action'>Action</a>
        ^                 ^      ^ // here you started " but not ended and remove the single quotes around Action
```

should be

```
<a href="index.php?filter=Action">Action</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Worked Like Magic

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you insert an opening and a closing php tag: `<?php` and `?>` To simplify it a bit you could just echo the value you get via `$_GET`

```
<h3>Filter Results</h3>
<p><a href="index.php?filter='Action'>Action</a></p>
<p><a href="index.php?filter='Comedy'>Comedy</a></p>
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['filter'])){
        echo $_GET['filter'];  
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `isset` will return true or false (it checks whether the variable is set or not). Change your code:

```
if(isset($_GET['filter']) && $_GET['filter'] == 'Action') {
```

Comment: Nothing is being ouputted ot the page

Comment: You should remove the single quotes in the `href` of your links. `...?filter=Action`.

Answer (score 1):

Your if condition is not correct do it:

```
if(isset($_GET['filter']) && $_GET['filter'] == 'Action'){
  echo 'Action';  
}
```

Similarly with else if:

```
else if(isset($_GET['filter']) && $_GET['filter'] =='Comedy') {
```

As you are comparing the `isset($_GET['filter'])` with the value although isset returns true of false so you need to compare the value of `$_GET['filter']`.

Answer (score 1):

`isset` returns `true` and since `'Action'` is not `null`, it evaluates to true.

```
if ((isset($_GET['filter'])) && ($_GET['filter'] == 'Action')) {
    // ...
} else if ((isset($_GET['filter'])) && ($_GET['filter'] == 'Comedy')) {
    // ...
}
```

BTW such code would sooner or later become a nightmare to maintain.

You could instead, for example

```
function preventDirectoryTraversal($requestParam) {
    return preg_replace("/\//", "", $requestParam);
}

// ...

if (isset($_GET['filter'])) {
    $filterName = preventDirectoryTraversal($_GET['filter']);
    include(FILTERS_DIR . "/" .  $filterName . ".php");
}
```

or something alike. Of course this can be further improved, but I hope you get the point.

Comment: What will be easiest way to write this code. I am new to PHP. thanks

Comment: @SamuelHughesMensah Well, the easy approach is not always a good one, but the above with the include seems to be sufficient for now. Then, you define a FILTERS_DIR constant that is the name of the folder into which you put the filters (actually, with filters, filter chaining is a good solution, but is out of scope for now). The files would be named filterName.php and based on the filter name, you include the appropriate functionality. Before this, you need to sanitize your request parameter coming from the user, otherwise the application would be vulnerable to directory traversal based attacks

Comment: Thanks for tip. I would use them when I am excellent with PHP but for now after reading the Other comments i would stick with switch statements.Thanks by the way

Comment: @SamuelHughesMensah You're welcome! It's not that difficult, however :) You just create a directory, putting filter code in there with files named the same as your filters, e.g. *"Action.php"* and then you `include` the filter file based on the filter name in the request.
An oversimplified version would be merely `include("filters/$_GET['filter'].php");` (no security and configurability added here)

Answer (score 1):

Wrong use of isset, [check documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), return a boolean.

```
if (isset($_GET['filter']))
{
    switch ($_GET['filter'])
    {
        case 'Action':
            //TODO
            break;
        case 'Comedy':
            // TODO
            break;
        default:
            // TODO
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really an answer. Provide only link. Try a comment.

Comment: Link only answers are not suited to StackOverflow. They are more suited to comments.

Comment: if(isset($_GET['filter']))
{
switch($_GET['filter'])
{
case 'Action':
//TODO
break;
case 'Comedy':
// TODO
break;
}
}

Answer (score 1):

you dont have to use isset() and then compare.

```
$filter = $_GET['filter'];

if(isset($filter)){
   if($filter == 'Action'){
     echo 'Action';
   }else if($filter == 'Comedy'){
     echo 'Comedy';
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//isset will always return true or false
if(isset($_GET['filter'])){

    if($_GET['filter']=='Action')
    {
        echo 'Action';

    }elseif($_GET['filter']=='Comedy'){

        echo 'Comedy';

    }

}
```